# Accessing a TCP socket from all activities

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, tcp, singleton

I want to create a TCP socket when a button is pressed in my first activity and then access that same socket object from any activity (not sure that closing and opening a socket in each activity is a good idea).

I tried quite a few methods having my mind set on a Singleton instance being the best solution to access an object though any activity, my problem is since this is a TCP socket I don't see AsyncTask as the smart idea (can only execute once, defies my point of having one instance of an object) and I don't see how I combine a regular Thread with a singleton.

Singleton code:

```
public class TCPSingleton extends Application {

    private static TCPSingleton singleInstance;
    String HostIP;
    int tcp_port;
    Socket clientSocket;
    DataOutputStream outToServer;


    public static TCPSingleton getInstance() {
      return singleInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();  
      singleInstance = this;
      singleInstance.initializeInstance();
    }

    protected void initializeInstance() {
        this.HostIP = "10.0.0.6";
        this.tcp_port = 9871;
        try {
            this.clientSocket = new Socket(this.HostIP, this.tcp_port);
            this.outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void send_data(String data){

        try {
            this.outToServer.writeBytes(data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

How do I merge a thread here (or what's the better idea other than singleton to do this).

Comment: Any thread can access `TCPSingleton.getInstance().send_data` and if you synchronize on `outToServer` (or use a lock) in the `send_data` method, the method can be safely used by any thread.

Comment: @vanOekel How can I call TCPSingleton.getInstance().send_data from the thread by itself (do I run the thread and close it for every time I want to send some data?)

Comment: The idea is that other threads use TCPSingleton like a regular (utility) object and TCPSingleton itself is not a thread. Only thing left to organize in your application is to call `onCreate()` before other threads start using TCPSingleton and `onDestroy()` is called before your application stops.